# Saving/storing/exporting large objects in C++

Tags: c++, vector, save, export, store

**Background:**

I am a new c++ programmer and am trying to build a program that returns a string stating the color of a given hex colorcode. The overall function is to request the hexcode of the pixel the mousepointer is on, and return a string that describes the color (like "Dark Red" for #8B0000). (I am colorblind, it would be a great help)

As a first try, I created a .txt file that contains all possible colorcodes on newlines. Needless to say, the document has 16777216 lines and is 134.2MB big. I have searched the internet and I've found that the only way to read a .txt file in C++ is line by line, start to end. That would result in 16777216 calls to "getline()" for the string "Black". This approach got my "hopeless" stamp on it for now.

**Idea:**

I would like to create a vector that contains 16777216 instances of (String colour) and use a hex-to-int conversion to use as an index to locate the correct String. This vector would also get quite big and pretty unhandy to build or use.

**Problem:**

I need to find the best way (if possible) to save/preserve a large object along with my c++ classes, so that I could just import the object and use it right away.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not the only way to read a file in C++... and that vector would be massive! Are you really going to have 16777216 different names for colours?

Comment: Is there a name for all colors ? (yeah, probably, but not very practical in real life situation)
Are you certain you really want to store the color RGB values of all available colors ? Why don't you just store the most common colors and decide of a way to group colors ? (see the HTML default colors or the X11 default colors (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa358802%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Sounds like a job for Fuzzy logic! There are very few people (if any) who would actually be able to tell the difference between #00aaab and #00aaac. XKCD did a study on what names people use for colours, it might help you categorise the ranges.

Comment: Use deque instead of vector for such a large dataset.

Answer (score 1):

A) Your file contains more than 16777216 lines, which means it contains more than the number of words in English, and probably Russian, Greek, Chinese and Japanese all combined.

B) You need to put things into ranges and then do a binary scan for the correct range. In other words map the range for navy blue as an object with a low and a high value into the range.

C) Put all the ranges into a big list and sort the list.

D) Then do a binary scan for any particular color and it will intersect the correct range.

For example:

```
// Navy blue might be this range
Low  = RGB(0,0,170)
High = RGB(0,0,200)

// Light Red might be this range
Low  = RGB(240,0,0)
High = RGB(255,0,0)
```

I mean, why would you want to name each color if you can name the range instead?

Comment: I had considered using ranges, however I figured needing to write a massive binary tree to get into the right branches.

I found the idea of using the hexToInt integer as an index value that immediatly pointed at the right color in some sort of "database" the most appealing.

But thanks anyway. :)

Comment: If you just used a binary ordered list(not a binary tree) then it would be much smaller and still very fast. How many text color names do you have?

Answer (score 0):

The OP posted:

> I have searched the internet and I've found that the only way to read a .txt file in C++ is line by line, start to end.

This is incorrect. I'm not sure what C++ file reading/writing classes you are using, but if the one you are using doesn't support random access, then find a different one.

If you reset back and use fopen, you can use fseek to go a specific place in the file.

If you format all the records in your file to be the same length, you can then easily calculate the offset into the file as `recordnumber*recordlength` (assuming the first record is number 0).

Comment: As a note of other file reading mechanisms that support dynamic access: `ifstream` has a `seekg` function to set the current read location

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the discussion David and Alex :)

Simple solution for one way lookups value to name

So let me suggest first quantize the color space based in the four MSBs of every color value.

```
val = ((hexval & 0xf00000) >> 12) | ((hexval & 0x00f000) >> 8) | ((hexval & 0x0000f0) >> 4)
```

Also create a `std::vector<std::string>` with 4096 entries into which you read the color names.

```
std::vector<std::string> names(4096);

//Read file and do for each line
names[val] = /*name for the value*/ 

//Lookup
const std::string& name = names[val];
```

For bidirectional lookup I would still look to `boost::bimap` it can be configured to look like a vector when finding the names from color values. And configured as a hash table when finding a color values that match a certain named color.

Comment: A potential solution, but fails when it comes to dealing with the nuances of human perception. The range of 'green' is not the same as the range of 'red'. Trying to give an agreeable name to an exact colour value is a very complex challenge.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "preserve" an object of a class then I suggest pickling it! Here is a [library](http://www.picklingtools.com/) that I think will work for c++

These routines come from chooser.h in that library and should be usefull

```
// C++
DumpValToFile (const Val& thing_to_serialize,
           const string& output_filename,
           Serialization_e how_to_dump_the_data);

LoadValFromFile (const string& input_filename,
             Val& result,
             Serialization_e how_data_was_dumped);
```

I believe the parameter Val& is where you pass the object needing to be pickeled

What these tools do is [serialize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization#C_and_C.2B.2B) an object so that it can be stored easily on a hardrive.

I have never used this tool personally, but I have used something similar  to it in python and so I suggest experimenting  with pickling things in Python first. Google "python pickle" for more information on that.

Answer (score -1):

I think you'll only want to actually 'name' a *very* small number of the possible 2^24 8-bit RGB values, so `std::map` is your friend here:

```
std::map<int, string> colors;

colors[0x000000] = "Black";
...
colors[0xFFFFFF] = "White";
```

You could start using the HTML color names from here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_colornames.asp

You'll also want to write a 'findNearest' function, (unless of course you actually have 16 million different names for colors). Your `findNearest` would compute the distance in RGB-space between each named colour and the target colour.

Comment: This is a disastrous idea! Maps are great for sparse data, but for dense data like this, you want a `vector`. There is simply too much of it to do it sensibly. The OP needs to decide how he is going to condense the colour space down before we can come up with a sensible solution.

Comment: In addition, you have a built in mapping scheme...if he really has 16M color names, his index is already built for him.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain - sighs deeply. So you seriously believe the OP has 2^24 sensible names for colours? I'm sure this *will* be sparse data, and due to the human eye/brain combo, the names will not be distributed evenly through the RGB colourspace, hence the need for a `findNearest` method as mentioned above. I'll try and clarify the answer a bit...

Comment: I did say... *The OP needs to decide how he is going to condense the colour space down before we can come up with a sensible solution.*

Comment: @AlexChamberlain - One advantage of a map is that it's basically precision independent. Rather than a 24-bit int, your key could be a triplet of R,G,B doubles.

Answer (score -2):

I would read it all into a `std::map` at the start of the program. Then use that map for fast lookups. If reading the text-file takes to long, consider converting it to some binary representation. Parsing the text file for every look-up will be slow.

If you want bidirectional lookups, i.e. from value to name and name to value. Check `boost::multi_index` 
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html
or `boost::bimap`
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html

I would also consider using boost::serialization to store and retrieve the data for the map in between runs.
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html

Comment: This is a disastrous idea! Maps are great for sparse data, but for dense data like this, you want a vector. There is simply too much of it to do it sensibly. The OP needs to decide how he is going to condense the colour space down before we can come up with a sensible solution.

Comment: Well I guess that would be true. But then I would look to hash maps. Then we get a compact representation and fast lookups. Or a soretd deque if lookup time is of no concern. A deque will consume less continuous memory. Again have a look at `boost::bimap` if you want two way lookups there is hased versions of it.

Comment: But I do agree that 2^24 names will take some time to write down ;) Might I suggest only using the 4 MSB of each color to quantize the color space. Then there are "only" 4096 names.

Comment: A `deque` or `vector` will be quicker than a hash map and use less memory in this case.

Comment: I care to hear a good motivation for this. To search the vector and deque is an O(N) operation. A good hash table is amortized O(1). Insertion might be faster for vectors. But that is usually only done once at startup. Then we want lookups to be a fast operation. Also a hash table does not use much more memory then a vector. The extra memory used for the table will be negligible. All of these solutions have a memory requirement that is O(N).

Comment: The hash is already built in...each color already has a unique key (24-bit RGB value) that can be used as the reference into the array or vector. Even if you quantize, you still can access the data in O(N). If you think about it, you are already using a hash map, just the hash function is really easy (and unique)

Comment: Depends what you mean by "To search"... Colours are just a 3-byte number, an offset into a vector. This is an O(1) operation. Hash tables use a whole load more memory, because to minimise collisions they have to stay empty to a certain extent. And hash tables are amortised O(1), not actually O(1).

Comment: Yes O(1), too much typing, not enough thinking...my point is that vector (or array directly) is the way to go. Although, he may have to resort to keeping the list on disk someplace. Because even if he only stores 10 bytes per entry, it's going to take 167MB of memory. Unless he's going frequent look ups, it's likely he's better served saving the RAM. I like the quantized approach described by @AxelOmega